# On Ubuntu, How can I uninstall or remove the lower version of selenium?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, appium

While using AppiumLibrary with RobotFramework, I am getting below error.

Error: importing test library 'AppiumLibrary' failed: 
ImportError: No module named switch_to

Here,PYTHONPATH: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg

To resolve above error I want to try solution mentioned at link "https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2625" which asks to remove the lower version of selenium.

I have two selenium folders at below location. 
Selenium folders:
1)/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium
2)/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium-2.44.0.egg-info
How can I remove the the selenium other than 2.44?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No process was required to uninstall Selenium.

I simply deleted the directory "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium". This resolved my error with Robot Framework.